# I'm installing postgres 9 on RHEL v7 (an AWS instance)

Tags: linux, postgresql

I am trying to follow the directions here:
http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/

I run this command as root:

```
service postgresql-9.4 initdb
```

This is what I see:

> The service command supports only basic LSB actions (start, stop,
>   restart, try-restart, reload, force-reload, status). For other
>   actions, please try to use systemctl.

What did I do wrong?  Or is this expected output?

Comment: Use the instructions for "Fedora >= 19", right below the ones you're using...

Comment: That helped.  I had to uninstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to uninstall Postgres and reinstall it a special way.

Here is how to uninstall it (as root issue this):

```
  yum remove postgresql
```

Here is how to install it.  As root, issue these commands:

```
 yum install postgresql-server
 postgresql-setup initdb
 systemctl enable postgresql.service
```